# Better way to make chat application?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Currently I'm making a chat application where only admin and users chat, no user-to-user chat . The design is: every chat is stored in database and each 2 seconds user and admin make an AJAX request (to a php file) to see if there is a new chat dialogue, and if there is, pull the data into the textbox. It all seems normal and working good.

Problem is as more user is talking to admin at the same time the AJAX request is becoming a lot, and by testing, the web performance already decreased with only 5 users chatting at the same time. And the input is slow too, every time user press enter they got to enter the data into database first before the admin can read it (and vice versa).

I have been told that using JSON is a recommended way, but I have no idea how to do it, can someone please at least tell me how's the design or flow is going to be if use JSON? Or is there a better way to make it? (by the way, using `node.js` is currently impossible for my current hosting, so don't put it in suggestion lists, sucks I know).

Comment: JSON is a serialization format, it wont magically fix latency. Look into _long polling_.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would think JSON could solve this performance problem.  Nor am I entirely clear on why 5 chat sessions is causing an issue.  I think you need to identify exactly **where the problem is** before attempting to change anything.  5 threads submitting db requests every 2 seconds should NOT be a performance issue unless your queries and data structures are beyond jacked up.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915819/building-a-chat-system-with-javascript

Comment: @ChrisLively: the performance problem is that the input area where admin type their message becomes very slow/lag...for instance I instantly type "my name is this" the result came out is something like "my nae s tis"

Answer (score 0):

You should change the AJAX responder phps output to JSON. (you can use the json_encode php function for example.) And you should parse(eval) this in javascript.

I am a bit sceptic. It think It could reduce the network usage by more than 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a message queue, like 0mq or rabbitmq.
There are a lot of chat examples around.